# Why is Fry's fro all frizzy?

Tags: futurama

Why does it get so frizzy so often?

How does this happen?

[image: Fry Fro Image]

Comment: I think I saw this question before

Comment: @DVK me too, but I think that one got deleted

Comment: The title of this question is a tongue-twister!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Fryfro](http://theinfosphere.org/Fryfro) is a running gag in Futurama. It's when Fry's hair puffs out as a result of ambient static electricity or Fry being electrocuted:

[image]

Here are some appearances of the Fryfro:

- [Hell Is Other Robots](http://theinfosphere.org/Hell_Is_Other_Robots): from ambient static electricity.
- [Rebirth](http://theinfosphere.org/Rebirth): from electrocution.
- [A Clockwork Origin](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Clockwork_Origin): from an electromagnetic pulse from a solar flare.

For whatever reason, it doesn't seem to happen to other characters.